# Reloading Website without stopping JS code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a JS script on a website (not my own) and I want it to refresh the website, in order to check for updates. However, I have only found code online for reloading the entire page (location.reload(true), etc...), which clears any code that I have running through the console. I am new to JS so is there any way to refresh a page and keep the JS code running? Also might there be a way to only reload load a certain portion of the page?

Basically,
Reload website without stopping code

Comment: jQuery.load() might be worth checking out.

Comment: `->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Seconding @Felix Kling's recommendation. AJAX allows one to reach out to the server for more information including JSON, HTML, etc. which can in turn be used to alter your existing view programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can easily load any part of a page from a URL using [AJAX](http://docforge.com/wiki/AJAX).  To fill the body element with the contents of a URL:

```
$('body').load('/page');
```

Your URL can respond with the segment of HTML you want to render, or you can request a full web page and grab just the segment you want buy adding a selector:

```
$('body').load('/page body');
```

The page isn't technically refreshed, just the HTML content inside the body (or whatever element you select) is replaced.  Any previously loaded header content like JS remains and keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to actually refresh the entire page without stopping the execution of the JavaScript code.

For doing updates on the page there would be two possibilities:

1. Use of **AJAX** (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) to check for new updates on the page. There are some very good tutorials out there on the internet – just google »AJAX JavaScript«.
2. Use of **IFRAME**. Make a page and stuck all the stuff in it and then put that page in an iframe and then reload the iframe instead of reloading the entire page.

Hope I could help you.